# How to calculate stays against 90/180 visa rules?

Tags: visas, schengen, tips-and-tricks, turkey, 90-180-visa-rules

Some destinations have a "90/180 rule" which says you can come and go but you must not spend over 90 days out of any 180 days in the area. [A recent question asked by a new contributor](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10379/schengen-visa-rejection) concerns this rule.

At least Schengen and Turkey have this rule, probably depending on where the traveller is from and what kind of visa they apply for.

Maybe I'm a dummy but I've always had a lot of trouble trying to add up how many days I've spent in such places when I've entered and left several times over recent months.

Is there an easy way to do this I'm missing or is it difficult for everybody? I'm guessing something based on counting backwards from the end date might be the trick?

Maybe you know of an app or website that can do this for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Surprisingly for me, I already managed to find two websites so far that can calculate this:

[`bodrumbulletin.com` provides one](http://www.bodrumbulletin.com/community/calculators/turkish-tourist-visa-calculator) for calculating Turkish visas:
[image: bodrumbulletin visa calculator]

---

`visacalc.com` provides a prettier one for calculating visas for "The European Union or Russia":
[image: visacalc visa calculator]

Answer (score 5):

[The European Commission has a calculator](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/schengen_calculator_en.html) as well, available in a “pop-over” from this [page about Border Crossing](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/index_en.htm). It comes with no guarantees (from the user's guide: “The calculator is a helping tool only”) and presumably gives the same results as other calculators but it's from a somewhat official source so hopefully it's maintained by people who know the rules inside out.

Comment: You inspired me to ask a question on English.SE! [To know something “inside out” or “inside and out”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165355)

Comment: @hippietrail Actually, I initially thought it was “inside out” but edited my draft after looking it up.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: https://www.vercalendario.info/en/how/border-schengen-days-visa.html

It may answer many questions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[www.schengen-calculator.com](http://www.schengen-calculator.com/) calculates this for you. Its easy to use but its just for schengen countries.

Comment: And how does one go about using the website? Be pedagogical. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The visa stay calculators are tricky to use in general, but this one (yes, it's mine!) is very intuitive: you just pick your date ranges on the full-sized calendar and it shows you in red which dates (if any) get you into trouble. When you've settled on a 'safe' itinerary, you just print the whole thing out and show it at the border if you run into trouble.

Better safe than sorry.

[SchengenCal.com](http://schengencal.com)

[image]

Comment: Site can't be reached as of Feb 2020.

Comment: Thanks @hippietrail it had https URL and no certificate set up. Should be fine now.

Comment: It is allowed to put in a link to your own website but it is in the rules that you put in the same post that it is your own site.

Answer (score 0):

Hey friends you can use https://www.visa-calculator.com to calculate remaining days in Schengen countries. It gives accurate results and easy to use.