# Are both the entry and exit day counted for 90/180 Schengen rule?

Tags: visas, schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

Suppose I enter Schengen region on a Monday at noon, and then leave at the same time the following monday.  Does this count as 7 days or 8 days?  If a day is measured as 24 hours then it would add up to 7, but if part days count in full then I guess it would be 8.

I am trying to make the most of my 90 days without risk of overstaying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: This answer is partially outdated, the rules is now 90 days, not 3 months. The EU commission [provides a calculator](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10399/how-to-calculate-stays-against-90-180-visa-rules/26289#26289) (albeit with a legal disclaimer) and you will find it uses calendar days, not hours.

---

As far as I can tell, what counts are the dates on the entry and exit stamps, which is also much easier to track and understand. Incidentally, I believe the rule is “three months”, not 90 days. I don't know if anybody tested these details in court and I would not volunteer to do it myself.

Relevant documents if you care to research this further: *EU visa code* and *Handbook for the processing of visa applications and the modification of issued visas* (both can be obtained from [the EU's website](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/)).

Comment: OK, so if one enters on Jan 1 and leaves on Jan 7 would it count as 6 days or 7?

Comment: @wim 7 days (and 8 days in the example in your question). Extrapolating from the lowest point, if you spend just a few minutes in transit, it still counts as 1 day.

Comment: I guess my answer is also: Without really solid information (which I am personally unable to provide), don't play with this and always go from the most conservative calculation. If you try to squeeze in an extra day and happen to be wrong, it could cost you dearly. Even if you have compelling reasons to believe your calculation is the right one, it can be a pain to have it recognized by the relevant authorities.