# Will a holiday during WHV in Germany deduct from a subsequent 90-day Schengen short-stay?

Tags: schengen, international-travel, eu

I'm from Australia currently on a working holiday visa in Germany. My visa expires on 14th October. I wish to stay until January 2015 if I travel/live visa free for another 90 days.

My question is: If I travel to Greece for 3 weeks in June, will that deduct from the 90 day period I would have after my working holiday runs out?

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, stays “[under a residence permit or a long-stay visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/does-tourist-visa-90-days-apply-after-a-working-holiday-visa-ends-in-schengen/24777#24777)” (including a work holiday visa) do not count toward the 90-day period but it's not entirely clear (to me, at least) if that also includes stays outside of the country that issued the long-stay visa.

But it doesn't matter in this case as there are more than 90 days between your trip outside Germany and your visa-free stay in the Schengen area! You could in principle travel to Greece in June and then stay 90 days in Germany three months later without ever breaking the [90-days-in-any-180-day-period rule](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule/21461#21461) **even without the long-stay visa**. You can verify that with [the online calculator](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10399/how-to-calculate-stays-against-90-180-visa-rules/26289#26289).

Additionally, there will be no obvious trace of your trip to Greece (no passport check, no stamp) so even if you stayed too long/later in the year, you might still get away with it.