# Can I leave the Schengen Zone before my student visa expires and come back as a tourist?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, legal

I'm studying in Denmark with a student visa, but it expires on July 14th and I've booked to stay in Europe for an extra month.

I already booked Airbnbs with friends on the July 15th and don't want to change the plans, so I was wondering whether I could leave the Schengen Zone and come back before it expires, but as a tourist.

Edit: Sorry, I'm an Australian citizen.

Comment: Some important details are missing but generally speaking, yes, that's possible, the time under a long-stay visa does not count towards the limit for short stays so you can certainly come back as a tourist, with or without visa as applicable. We already have several related questions like http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26716/will-a-holiday-during-whv-in-germany-deduct-from-a-subsequent-90-day-schengen-sh and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/does-tourist-visa-90-days-apply-after-a-working-holiday-visa-ends-in-schengen

Answer (score -2):

You cannot, for two main reasons:

1. Your visa is no longer valid for the purpose of your trip.
2. Schengen visas needs to be valid for the entire duration of your stay in the Schengen area. This means that not only does the visa need to be valid for when you are entering the Schengen zone, but it has to be valid throughout your intended period of stay.

   For example, your visa is expiring on July 14th; if you were to enter the    Schengen zone (of course, as a student) on July 13th, you can only stay for one day.

So it is best to leave early (so you don't overstay) and apply for a tourist visa (if you need one).

Comment: OP could be a citizen of an Annex II country, so the above wouldn't apply.

Comment: If you are in the Schengen zone on a student visa (as the OP is), then the first two points apply. If they are exempt from visa requirements, then they need to declare the same and they cannot enter on their student visa for purposes other than studies.

Comment: Didn't ask to come back on the student visa.  Asked if he/she could come back as a tourist.  I edited to clarify.

Comment: (-1) You seem to be confused both about the question and about the rules. It's not obvious that you would need to leave and reenter to switch from a long-stay status to a short-stay status (it's switching in the other direction that's often explicitly forbidden) but in any case the question is precisely about reentering as a tourist and your answer entirely fails to address that issue.

Comment: @Relaxed: BK's name suggested to me the possibility that English is not his native language, and the last sentence was less clear before my edit.

Comment: +1, @Relaxed has it wrong according to Elspeth Guild's clarification of the Schengen rules.

Comment: @Relaxed he is asking, quite simply - "if I am a student, and I want to stay longer than my studies, can I exit and enter again as a tourist on the same visa?" - my answer addresses both.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid You're using quotation marks but you just made that up "on the same visa" is nowhere to be found in the question. Your answer does nothing to clarify when that's allowed or not.

Comment: @GayotFow What is wrong specifcally? And can you quote something more authoritative than some random name dropping? Because in case you haven't noticed, Burhan's answer directly contradicts the Borders code, it is certainly possible to reenter for a short stay shortly after a long stay.

Comment: @Relaxed, I certainly wouldn't call it 'random name dropping', LOL.  And it does not contradict the Borders Code; honestly if you find something in the Borders Code that says a person can be in Schengen without permission, do let me know.

Comment: @GayotFow I just did and stand by it. But coming back to the matter at hand: I obviously did not say anything remotely close to that, stop being disingeneous and evasive. Once more, from the beginning: The OP asks if a short-stay as a tourist is possible after having been a student, the Borders code explicitly states that "Periods of stay authorised under a residence permit or a long-stay visa shall not be taken into account in the calculation of the duration of stay on the territory of the Member States".

Comment: Burhan says no (without any qualification or nuance) and I say that's obviously incorrect in light of the bits of the Borders code I just quoted. I don't know what you mean by "it" in "it does not contradict the Borders Code" but the answer most certainly directly contradicts the Borders code. So again, what is incorrect in my comment and how do you justify upvoting an inaccurate and misleading answer?

Comment: I obviously agree that you may not visit the Schengen area as a third-country national without either a short-stay visa or being exempt from the visa requirement by vritue your citizenship but that's a trivial point and you certainly don't need to invoke Elspeth Guild to make it. (And, incidentally, the answer also fails to make that point clearly, just muddying the issue further rather than clarifying under which conditions  reentering for a tourist stay is indeed possible and when it is not).

Comment: @Relaxed, I am aware of what the Borders Code says. I am also aware that it says "...Periods of stay authorised under a residence permit or a long-stay visa shall not be taken into account in the calculation of the duration of stay on the territory of the Member States..."; our difference is that I think this statement does not obviate the need for permission to be in the zone and hence that a student visa does not *automatically*  convert to a short-stay visa on its expiry. I checked. Name dropping notwithstanding. LOL, sorry.

Comment: @GayotFow We could discuss that at length somewhere else but that's a detail in this case as the OP explicitly said he or she would leave and reenter. I merely wrote that it is not *obvious* that this was needed. Meanwhile, Burhan's answer does not deal with this at all and is incorrect in other ways so unless you are deliberately trying to pick a fight with me there is no reason to focus on that. Therefore I ask again: What exactly justifies upvoting this answer when it completely fails to address the question and blatantly contradicts the Borders code?

Comment: @Relaxed heaven knows I am not trying to pick a fight. Bertram explains that the day counting exemption only works if the OP has permission to be in the zone in the first instance. This is unassailably correct. Reentering the zone on a student visa will not affect its expiry. This is also correct at first principles. So the OP's permission to be in the zone will expire on 14/7, and it will not be extended simply because the OP has exited/reentered using an existing visa. So Bertram advisers the OP that they need to adjust their status upon reentry. Totally correct.

Comment: @GayotFow Do you mean Burhan? The answer does nothing to clarify all this and that's highly debatable anyway.

Comment: @Relaxed yes Burhan, sorry. He wrote "... and apply for a tourist visa (if you need one)..." which is correct *OR* get a short-stay stamp (which he didn't say). This is very sound advice.  Otherwise the OP will be unable to prove they are not overstaying a student visa. If you find it debatable, I'm sorry, but it's certainly not picking a fight.

Comment: @GayotFow Initially, what he actually wrote is that the person should apply for a tourist visa, with no qualification whatsoever (whereas there is no such thing and we don't even know whether the OP could get a short-stay visa or would enter as a visa exempt national). The answer still does not get into the details you just mentioned and fails to clarify many important points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41160/discussion-between-relaxed-and-gayot-fow).