# Does re-entering Italy restart the 3 month visitation limit?

Tags: schengen, italy, multiple-entry, 90-180-visa-rules

I am going to visit Italy for several months. Italy allows visitors to vacation for 3 months. However, I plan to visit Italy a month and a half then visit another country for several weeks. When I re-enter Italy, does my 3 month visitation limit re-start? I heard that if I re-enter it, my 3 months re-starts. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not correct. You cannot in any case stay longer than 90 days in any 180-day period and you need to leave the entire Schengen area, otherwise the clock is still running. Even then, you need to spend 90 days outside of the Schengen area (e.g. UK, Croatia, etc.) to get another 90 days in Italy. You can use this [calculator](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10399/how-to-calculate-stays-against-90-180-visa-rules/26289#26289) to check exactly how long you can stay.

See [How does the Schengen 90/180 rule work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule) and [Sweden to Cyprus and back](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30565/sweden-to-cyprus-and-back)

Answer (score 0):

Your entry visit will likely be valid for the entire Schengen area, and to "leave" and come back, you'll have to leave the Schengen area.

Comment: It's true but would still not be enough to get another three months of stay.