# Staying more than 90 days in the Schengen area with a multiple-entry visa

Tags: schengen

I stayed in Italy for a total of 90 days with my 1-year multiple-entry visa. I came back on June 18th. Can I still go back and spend another 90 days this July. The visa will expire in January 2015.

Comment: You need to specify exactly when you entered and left the Schengen area see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stay for 90 days, leave the Schengen area and reenter immediately. You have to wait another 90 days before coming back, see [How does the Schengen 90/180 rule work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule/21461#21461). So if you have been in the Schengen area during the 90 days between March 21 and June 18, you cannot reenter before September 17.

But since your visa is valid for more than 6 months, “90 days” in the “DURATION OF VISIT” field on the visa sticker means 90 days in every six-month period. You can therefore stay up to 180 days in total between January 2014 and January 2015, provided you never stay more than 90 days in any 180-day period. Depending on when you entered and left the Schengen, it might therefore be possible to come back before September. The rule is a little complicated so you might want to use [the calculator](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10399/how-to-calculate-stays-against-90-180-visa-rules/26289#26289) to check what is and isn't allowed.