# What does "MULT" in a Schengen visa mean?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I have applied for a Schengen visa. I think I applied for a single-entry visa.

But now when I received my passport I can see that the number of entries is written as MULT.

Does this mean I have a multiple-entry visa or is MULT another code word for single-entry visa?

My duration of stay is 35 days.

Similar to this

[image: Multi Entry Visa]

Comment: They gave you a multiple entry visa. They sometimes do that at their own discretion.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus that's really the only answer possible to this question, isn't it?  You might as well write it up as one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "MULT" means? How can I use this visa for more than 2 entries to Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35302/what-is-the-mult-means-how-can-i-use-this-visa-for-more-than-2-entries-to-sch)

Comment: @Dirty-flow despite its title, the proposed duplicate question is about the application of the 90/180 rule to a multiple-entry visa, not about the meaning of *MULT* itself.

Comment: It would be pretty ridiculous if "MULT" was short for "single-entry," haha. But I wouldn't put it past a government somewhere to have done something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MULT means it is a multiple-entry visa.  From Annex VII of the [Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412):

> 3. ‘NUMBER OF ENTRIES’ heading:
>
>    This heading shows the number of times the visa holder may enter the territory for which the visa is valid, i.e. it refers to the number of periods of stay which may be spread over the entire period of validity, see 4.
>
>    The number of entries may be one, two or more. This number is written to the right-hand side of the preprinted part, using ‘01’, ‘02’ or the abbreviation ‘MULT’, where the visa authorises more than two entries.
>
>    ...